# Triggering action on route change with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm creating a small application with react, redux and react-router.

I have a list of items wrapped in `<Link />`, and when I click one of them, I want the item to be set as the `currentItem` in the state before triggering the link action. There's an action to do that - `selectItem(item)` - but I don't know how to trigger it.

Should I trigger it on `componentWillUnmount`? In that case - how do I figure out what item was clicked? Should I create an `<Link onClick={}/>` handler that dispatches the action?

The item page will then check whether or not the currentItem is set, and potentially fetch it from the back end if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that using Link works great.

**You can use it in a way that you have access to the event and the value of the originating component. Like this:**

`<Link to={address} onClick={actions.handlerFunction}>`

Where handlerFunction is a redux action creator. Then in your handlerFunciton you can access the event and the value of the element like this: `event.target.value`.
Your action creator should look something like this:

```
export function handlerFunction(event) {
    return {
        type: 'CHANGE_SOMETHING',
        prop: event.target.value
    }       
}
```

Then you can set the state in your reducer.

**If you don't need the event, but want to pass some data to the action creator you can just use it like this:**

`<Link to={address} onClick={() => actions.handlerFunction(someData)}>`

It is important to add the `to` property to the Link, it will update the address you see in the address bar.

[See more in the Link docs on github.](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using the `componentWillReceiveProps` in your "root" component, and compare the `nextProps` with `this.props`.
The router passes props to the component (**location**, **history** etc.) and you can juggle with those.

For example:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and in your **App** component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if (nextProps.location.pathname != this.props.location.pathname) {
// do stuff
}
```

P.S. I'm still a react noob, so please comment if you have advices or suggestions regarding this method.

Answer (score 1):

With the new `useEffect` and `useRef` helpers from the last React update, you can do like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

function Bob({ location: { key } }: RouteComponentProps) {
  const oldURL = useRef(key); // key is a unique identifier set by react-router

  useEffect(() => {
    if (oldURL.current !== key) {
      // trigger your action here
    }
    oldURL.current = key; // refresh the oldURL after every render
  });
}

export default withRouter(Bob);
```

`useRef` is needed to keep the old value in memory.

Then, you compare the old `location.key` with the new one.

If you compare `location.pathname`, the changes in the search params won't be detected, because the pathname only takes the text between the domain name and the search params:

```
htpp://foo.bar/products?filterBy=price
       ^           ^         ^
 domain name | pathname | search params
```

By comparing the `location.key`, your action will be triggered even if `filterBy` changes.
Not with `location.pathname`.